# Show the final ".00" on exact numbers php

Tags: php, number-formatting, money-format

00" on the exact numbers, but only showing the thousand separator too.
Here is a example:

```
number_format(1256, 2, '.', ',');
```

that show me : 1,256 and I need that this show: 1,256.00

I tried with money format, this is that happened:

```
money_format('%i', 1256);
```

the result of this is: 1256.00 like you can see this method don't return the thousand separator...

Thanks for the help.

```
$form['field name']->setData(number_format(1256, 2, '.', ','));
```

Comment: It produces `1256.00` for me (and 100 other PHP versions [here](http://3v4l.org/OAZgM)). Are you sure?

Comment: @AmalMurali he wants the , between the 1 and 2

Comment: have you tried `number_format(money_format('%i', 1256));` ?

Comment: yes, I dont know why.. I only set that a form's textbox like string...

Comment: Can you show more code? `number_format(1256, 2, '.', ',')` definitely shows `1,256.00`

Comment: I actually get 1,256.00

Comment: @CodeBird: That's the exactly what it does. For me, it produces the output `1,256.00`. And to quote the OP: "that show me : 1,256 and **I need that this show: 1,256.00**"

Comment: you can use setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US'); I think this will work.

Comment: All MasudianPour that resolve the number like my first example

Comment: I'd suspect the *setData* method... *number_format* 's role in life is exactly what you ask it to do!

Comment: I have updated the code, please review that...

Comment: Are you sure you are not converting the data to a float somewhere later on in your code?

Comment: yes, the setData method only insert that like a String...

Comment: Break the problem down, start by echoing out `number_format(1256, 2, '.', ',')` as I do not think that is your problem, the problem is coming from the assigning to a variable or the later display of it

Comment: It's done thanks on a moment i post the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Just put it together:

```
number_format(money_format('%i', 1256), 2, '.', ',');
```

See [this demo](http://codepad.org/ipRLPSk2).

Comment: This isn't required. The OP's code should work perfectly (at least for what he's trying to do), it's just that he's having some trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the locale as follows:

```
$number = 12354.65;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number);
```

[FIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r0q-j5s)

Comment: For `1256`, this produces `1256.00` (it doesn't include the thousands separator).

Comment: @AmalMurali , no that's wrong, it produces 1,256.00 see [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gem-7xe)

Comment: It works on *that* fiddle. But doesn't work on my system, [here](http://3v4l.org/YVhFT), [here](http://codepad.org/J2pDc0EU), [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4u60fe) or [here](https://eval.in/102417). `setlocale()` is not guaranteed to work everywhere, so I wouldn't use it.

Comment: you need to try it on your own system, fiddle applications may prevent such functions for some reason, but other than that it has its effect

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all... that was only a trouble with the "()" order...

that was:

```
$form['filed name']->setData(numberformat(1256), 2, '.', ',');
```

And that is the reason because the number format doesn't work completely...

Comment: That was not what you showed in your question. So are you saying this is the faulty code or this is the answer as this would not work properly where the code you put in your question would.

Comment: @ring0 Unfortunately I do not have sufficient rep to vote, but this would be a good candidate